# Correlation coefficient of matrices (2d arrays)

Tags: correlation, image-processing, cross-correlation

I need to compute the correlation coefficient between two digital images so that I can compare those two images [to test their similarities](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50282799_Multidirectional_Scratch_Detection_and_Restoration_in_Digitized_Old_Images).

I can convert the images either to two [matrices of complex numbers](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Imaging/ComplexImage.cs) (the complex representation of the images are Fourier Transformed so that I can work in frequency domain) or to two [matrices of real numbers](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/Converters/ImageToMatrix.cs). So, those are my options to get started with.

**How can I calculate the correlation coefficient of two matrices (or 2d arrays)?**

[This routine](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Math/Metrics/PearsonCorrelation.cs) can calculate correlation coefficient of two vectors (or 1d arrays). But, I need to calculate the correlation of two matrices (or, 2d arrays).

Comment: It's unclear at least to me what "the Correlation Coefficient of a matrix" would be even for a matrix with real elements.

Comment: What is your intended use? There is more than one possible definition for correlation in the case of complex numbers. See for instance the abstract of http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4471891&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F78%2F4471869%2F04471891.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4471891 .  I don't ha e access to that paper.  How the real and imaginary points of correlation are crunched down into a single real number is the tricky part. I suggest you do some Googling and reading.

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which the values of an "image" are *complex* numbers and how those are related to the real numbers you also describe?  Then, with this context in mind, please tell us what this "correlation coefficient' is intended to tell you about the images.

Comment: @whuber, https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Imaging/ComplexImage.cs

Comment: @whuber, https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/Converters/ImageToMatrix.cs

Comment: @whuber, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50282799_Multidirectional_Scratch_Detection_and_Restoration_in_Digitized_Old_Images

...

Read 2.3.1 - Core Detection.

Comment: A quick look at your references confirms my suspicions that you might be wanting to work with Fourier transforms.  Due to the intimate relationship between FTs and correlations, failure to mention that is going to get you either no answers, inferior answers, or irrelevant answers.  I would suggest not asking for a particular procedure but instead explaining (a) what data you are starting with and (b) what you want to accomplish with them.  Then your question might have a better chance of getting answers that are genuinely useful to you.

Comment: @whuber, I did mention Fourier Transform in my question.

Comment: Yes, but in a potentially deceptive way that suggests your data are not yet Fourier transforms.  And if they are not, then I am still wondering just what you need a complex representation of your image for.  What exactly is a "complex" image?  Or is it merely the case that all the imaginary parts of the pixels are set to zero?